# PHP contact form will just refresh the page after submission.

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

After searching for about 3 hours i still can't figure this one out.
I Have a html template with a contact form and im trying to make it work using a PHP script.
I changed the template to PHP and pasted the PHP form script in it. everything is working fine except the confirmation text.
After a successful submission it will just refresh the page instead of printing "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback". i do not want a redirect, i just want it to print on the same page.

Any ideas?
I got a sample of my code.

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contact-form" method="post" class="form afsana-form" role="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control afsana-style" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" type="text" required autofocus />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control afsana-style" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary afsana-btn" name="submit" value="verzenden" type="submit">Verzenden <i class="ion-arrow-graph-up-right"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["message"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['email'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = (Contact_form);
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("something@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the source code for the page that's rendered? Without tags around your text, the text may not render in your browser.

Comment: your form action is the same page, so it will always submit back to that page telling your browser to re-navigate there. You need to look into AJAX in order to submit the form without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have this: `$subject = (Contact_form);` which should throw an error, so I assume you have error reporting turned off. When developing, you should have error reporting on so you can see errors in your code... Else you are just working blind. I don't mean by throwing tacky `error_reporting(0)` in every file either, I mean to set your error reporting level to `E_ALL` in your `php.ini`.

You also have: `$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n";`
However, `$email2` is not defined anywhere, so you would get an error here too.. which is why it's important to test with error reporting **on**.

See if this works:

```
    <?php

    $error = '';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if ( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message']) )
        {

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if ( $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
            {
                $subject = '(Contact_form)';
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                $headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email

                $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

                if ( $result = mail("something@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
                    $error = 'Success';
                } else {
                    $error = 'There was an error sending your email!';
                }

            } else {
                $error = 'Invalid Email Address!';
            }


        } else {
            $error = 'Please fill all fields.';
        }
    }

?>

<p><?= $error ?></p>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" /><br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in $subject just a string value like:

```
$subject = 'Test subject';
```

change also the following line to this (there is no $email2 defined):

```
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
```

and give it a try. You can also put as first line of your code

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

and check for errors when submiting the form.

Comment: it's not the only error he has ;) There is an undefined variable lying in there...

Comment: @WadeShuler yes you are right. There is the $email2 that it is not defined anywhere...